# Count Formula Results In Filtered/Unfiltered List

Tags: excel-2003

In column B (with a named range of 'OutputName') of my spreadsheet I'm using the following formula within each cell to extract data from an input sheet to a 'Summary' page populating each cell with a user's name.

```
=If(ROWS(B$7:B7)<=$C$3,INDEX(INDIRECT(B$6),SMALL(If(Status=$B$3,ROW(Status)-ROW(Input!$B$7)+1),ROWS(B$7:B7))),"")
```

Then, to perform a count of these unique formulae results within the range, I'm using the following 'COUNTIF' statement: `=COUNTA(OutputName)-COUNTIF(OutputName,"")`

The formula works fine when the list is unfiltered, but when I apply an autofilter to another column within my data range this unique count fails to update to show the correct number of 'Filtered Unique Values'.

How I can adapt my formula to count the unique values whilst the list is either filtered or unfiltered?

Comment: Hi @pnuts, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. Since posting my original question, I've been working on this and I've been able to find a work around this. Rather than applying more formula to allow for autofilters, I've added a series of drop down menus which allows the user to filter the information which populates the spreadsheet and maintains the 'Countif'formula. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: HI @pnuts,my apologies. COnsider this done. Kind regards and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since posting my original question, I've been working on this and I've been able to find a work around this. Rather than applying more formula to allow for autofilters, I've added a series of drop down menus which allows the user to filter the information which populates the spreadsheet and maintains the 'Countif'formula.